# Exterior power of a tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, multilinear-algebra, vector-bundles

Given 2 vector bundles $E$ and $F$ of ranks $r_1, r_2$, we can define $k$'th exterior power $\wedge^k (E \otimes F)$.

Is there some simple way to decompose this into tensor products of various exterior powers of individual bundles?

I am interested in the case when $F$ corresponds to the twisted line bundles $\mathcal{O}(k)$.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no general decomposition but it can be fibered into $\wedge^i E \otimes \wedge^{k-i} F$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the special case when $F$ has rank $1$, the canonical homomorphism
$$ (E\otimes F)^{\otimes k}\to (\wedge^k E)\otimes (F^{\otimes k})$$
induces a homomorphism
$$ \wedge^k (E\otimes F)\to (\wedge^k E)\otimes (F^{\otimes k}).$$
This is because for all $u\in E$ and all $v_1, v_2\in F$, we have $(u\otimes v_1)\wedge (u\otimes v_2)=0$ (locally $v_i=a_ie$ with $a_i$ scalar and $e$ a basis, so the exterior product vanishes locally, hence vanishes globally). Now again locally (when $F$ is the trivial line the bundle), this homomorphism is clearly an isomorphism. So it is an isomorphism globally:
$$ \wedge^k (E\otimes F)\simeq (\wedge^k E)\otimes (F^{\otimes k}).$$

Comment: Thanks. If $F$ (rank > 1) can be resolved in terms of line bundles, one can say something about the general case as well.

Comment: @Amit: sorry, I don't see how.

Comment: You won't get a formula like the one you gave for the case of line bundle. If $0 \rightarrow N_1 \rightarrow \oplus L_i \rightarrow F \rightarrow 0$ be a resolution of $F$, then you can get $\wedge^k (E \otimes F)$ as a quotient of $\wedge^k (E \otimes \oplus L_i)$ and terms coming from the filtration of $\wedge^k (E \otimes \oplus L_i)$ and various exterior products involving $N$. Try writing down the case for $k = 2$. For higher $k$, one can use induction.

Answer (score 12):

If $E$ and $F$ are arbitrary, decomposing $\bigwedge^k(E\otimes F)$ in terms of 
$\bigwedge^i E$ and $\bigwedge^j F$ for $i,j\leqslant k$ is quite subtle, and involves $\lambda$-rings (in fact, is inspiration for them). See [this blog post](http://concretenonsense.wordpress.com/2009/07/23/lambda-rings/) for more details. Essentially, one looks at the action of the product $S_k\times S_k$ of symmetric groups on the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z[X_,\dots,X_k,Y_1,\dots,Y_k]$. The theory of symmetric polynomials tells us that for the elementary symmetric polynomials $E_1,\dots,E_k$ in the $X_i$ and $F_1,\dots,F_k$ in th $Y_i$, one has 
$$
  \mathbb Z[X_1,\dots,X_k,Y_1,\dots,Y_k]^{S_k\times S_k} = \mathbb Z[E_1,\dots,E_k,F_1,\dots,F_k] \text{.}
$$
Since the formal power series
$$
  \prod_{i,j\geqslant 1} (1+X_i Y_jT)
$$
is invariant under permutations of the $X_i$ and $Y_j$, we have 
$$
  \prod_{i,j\geqslant 1} (1+X_i Y_jT) = \sum_{k\geqslant 0} P_k(E_1,\dots,E_k,F_1,\dots,F_k) T^k \text{.}
$$
It turns out that 
$$
  \textstyle\bigwedge^k(E\otimes F) = P_k(E,\textstyle\bigwedge^2 E,\ldots,\textstyle\bigwedge^k E, F, \textstyle\bigwedge^2 F,\ldots,\textstyle\bigwedge^k F)
$$
where we interpret $V+W$ as $V\oplus W$ and $V\cdot W$ as $V\otimes W$.

All of this as a natural framework in $K$-theory. Briefly, if $X$ is a ringed space, the group $K_0(X)$ is the free abelian group generated by locally free sheaves on $X$, modulo the relation $[\mathscr E]+[\mathscr F]=[\mathscr G]$ whenever there is an exact sequence 
$$
  0 \to \mathscr E \to \mathscr G \to \mathscr F \to 0
$$
The operation $[\mathscr E]\cdot [\mathscr F]=[\mathscr E\otimes \mathscr F]$ gives $K_0(X)$ the structure of a commutative ring. Even better, $K_0(X)$ is a *$\lambda$-ring*, with operations $\lambda^k:K_0(X) \to K_0(X)$ induced by 
$\lambda^k[\mathscr E] = [\bigwedge^k \mathscr E]$. The $\lambda$-ring structure on $K_0(X)$ features prominantly in the [Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%E2%80%93Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem), a far-reaching generalization of the usual [Riemann-Roch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem) for line bundles on compact connected Riemann surfaces.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a nice description in terms of Schur functor and [Young diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau).

A Young diagram $\lambda$ is a picture made by a finite set of cells, left-aligned in rows, such that the length of the rows decreases going down. Any Young diagram can be transposed (exchanging rows and columns) to obtain another Young diagram $\lambda'$.

To any Young diagram you can associate a functor $S_\lambda$, called Schur functor, which is an endofunctor of the category of finite vector spaces over a fixed field. The way how the Schur functor is constructed starting from the Young diagram is a rather complicated and you can find the details in [this page of ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Schur+functor).

To make an example, the Schur functor associated to a diagram made by only one row with $n$ cells is the functor sending any vector space $V$ to the vector space of symmetric $n$-powers $Sym^n(V)$, while the transposed diagram gives the exterior $n$-powers $\Lambda^n(V)$.

The product of two Schur functors can be decomposed into the linear combination of other Schur functors thanks to the [Littlewood–Richardson rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Richardson_rule).

The application of this rule in the case of the $n$th exterior power of a tensor product yields the following formula:

$\Lambda^n(V \otimes W) = \bigoplus (S_\lambda(V) \otimes S_{\lambda'}(W))$

where $\lambda$ in the direct sum runs over al the Young diagrams with $n$ cells and at most dim($V$) rows and dim($W$) columns.

You can find a reference for this formula in Fulton, Harris, *Representation Theory*, exercise 6.11.

[edit: this is an expaned comment based on the hint given in this mathoverflow discussion:
[mathoverflow.net/questions/126219/exterior-and-symmetric-powers-of-external-tensor-products-of-representations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126219/exterior-and-symmetric-powers-of-external-tensor-products-of-representations)]

Comment: Though this may answer the question it is good to provide the essence of the link in the answer

Comment: Ok, I expand my answer. Even though, ifI have to be honest, I don't know much about them too, since I am still working on it :-)