# Does the tensor product commute with the exterior product?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R,S$ be commutative rings, $S$ an extension of $R$ and $A$ a $R$-module.

> Is it true that $(\bigwedge^{k} A) \otimes_{R} S = \bigwedge^{k} (A \otimes_{R} S)$?

I was trying to use the universal properties of the exterior algebra and the tensor product, but without much success. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your rings have to be commutative for this to make sense, so it is a good idea to make that explicit.

Comment: In any case, yes, that works (provided on the left you take exterior powers of $A$ as an $R$-module and on the right of $A\otimes_RS$ as an $S$-module. It should follow from the universal property quite directly.

Comment: Thank you Mariano, I edited the question. Could you please provide some details? I could not do it from there, but I don't have too much experience with universal properties...

Comment: I propose that instead you write down in the question what the universal property characterizing the right hand sided of the isomorphism you want is. Then we'll see.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211561/exterior-power-of-a-tensor-product