# Exterior Power of a Tensor Product in case one is a line bundle

Tags: tensor-products, vector-bundles, exterior-algebra, line-bundles

I was reading this thread [Exterior power of a tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211561/exterior-power-of-a-tensor-product) and I found that the result cited in first answer is very useful to me, but I couldn't prove it myself and what's said there is not enough for me. Can you give me a good reference?