# Unclear construction in Hitchins paper on Integrable Systems

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, principal-bundles, moduli-space, integrable-systems

In the paper [Stable Bundles and Integrable Systems](https://math.mit.edu/events/talbot/2011/library/hitchin_stable_bundles_integrable_systems.pdf) (1987), Hitchin shows that the cotangent bundles of moduli spaces of stable bundles can be viewed as integrable systems.

In section 4 of the paper, he constructs a mapping
$$p:H^0(M;\ \text{ad}P\otimes K)\to H^0(M;\ K^d)$$
based on an invariant homogeneous polynomial $p$ of degree $d$ on a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (which he later uses to construct hamiltonians). He justifies this construction by stating that the vector bundle $\text{ad}P$ is a bundle of Lie algebras each isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$.

Here, $P$ is a stable holomorphic principal $G$-bundle over a compact Riemann surface $M$ of genus $g>1$, with $G$ a semisimple complex Lie group, and $K$ is the canonical line bundle on $M$.

I do not understand how exactly we construct a mapping $H^0(M;\ \text{ad}P\otimes K)\to H^0(M;\ K^d)$, given the polynomial $p$?

All other discussions of the Hitchin system that I have seen (that came out some years after Hitchins original paper, for example [here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/balasubramanian/zmp/notes/Brochier.pdf) and [here](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ejbm18/introductiontohiggsbundles.pdf)) employ a notion of Higgs bundles in the construction of the Hitchin system and do not directly mention the above mapping. I would therefore be very grateful for help.

Edit: Previously, I also included the following question (resolved due to comments below):
I understand that each fibre of the associated bundle $\text{ad }P$ is a Lie algebra; however, I am not sure how to show that they are mutually isomorphic, and hence all isomorphic to a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Furthermore, is $\mathfrak{g}$ in this case the Lie algebra associated to $G$ (I don't believe that it is for [principle bundles and adjoint representations in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation))?

Comment: Note "principal bundle" refers to $P$ whose fibres are isomorphic to $G$. The bundle with Lie algebra fibres is $\operatorname{ad}P$. This is an example of what is called an "associated bundle" to $P$ and has fibres isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$ by definition.

Comment: Thank you! I also understand why the fibres are isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$ (the lie algebra associated with $G$) now - I had forgotten that $G$ acts freely and transitively on the fibres of $P$. I am still unclear on the construction of $p$.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably helpful to consider the case of vector bundles first, where we can replace $\text{Ad}(P)$ by $\text{End}(E)$ for a given vector bundle $E\to\Sigma$. In this case, a section of $\text{End}(E)$ can be viewed as a family of matrices which is parameterised by the base $\Sigma$. Say $\varphi\in H^{1,0}(\Sigma,\text{End}(E))\cong H^0(\Sigma,\text{End}(E)\otimes K)$ (Serre duality) and represent it by a $1$-form also denoted $\varphi$. Then we can define $\varphi\mapsto\text{tr}(\wedge^d\varphi)$ where $\wedge^d\varphi:\wedge^d E\to\wedge^d(E\otimes K)$. But now, we can use the fact that $\wedge^d(E\otimes K)=\wedge^dE\otimes K^{\otimes d}$, which is true because $K$ is a line bundle (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211561/exterior-power-of-a-tensor-product) for instance). So locally, we have that $\wedge^d\varphi$ can be written as $\sum A_i\otimes\eta_i$ with $A_i$ an endomorphism of $\wedge^dE$, and $\eta_i$ a section of $K^{\otimes d}$. The trace map is obtained by just taking the trace of each $A_i$. So we are left with $\sum \text{tr}(A_i)\eta_i\in H^0(U,K^{\otimes d})$, and likewise globally $\text{tr}(\wedge^d\varphi)\in H^0(\Sigma,K^{\otimes d})$.

So when $\mathfrak{g}=\text{End}(V)$ for a vector space $V$, then we have $\det(\lambda-\varphi)=\lambda^r+\sum_{k=1}^r\text{tr}(\wedge^k\varphi)\lambda^{r-k}$ and so these coefficients (which are known to be $\text{Ad}$-invariant homogeneous polynomials) are a natural choice. When we look at more general principal bundles, we have to fix some $\text{Ad}$-invariant homogeneous polynomials on the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. But besides that, the idea is exactly the same and you should be able to copy the construction I outlined above in the case of principal bundles. I'll leave that for you to write down as it's probably a useful exercise to make sure you understood the concept.

Comment: Thank you, I think you help me grasp the general ideas. For $\varphi\in H^0(M;\ \text{ad}P\otimes K)$ and $p\in M$, I have $\varphi(p)=q\otimes \eta$ for some $q\in \text{ad}P$ and $\eta\in K$. I understand that $q$ is in one of the fibres of $\text{ad}P$, and so I could apply the polynomial $p$ to $q$ - but instead, I want to look at $\wedge^k(q\otimes \eta)$ and use $\wedge^d(\text{ad}P\otimes K)\cong\wedge^d\ \text{ad}P\otimes\wedge^d\ K$ - but how could I apply $p$ to an element of $\wedge^d\ \text{ad}P$?

Comment: You would not use the exterior powers if you're doing the more general case of principal bundles. The traces of the exterior powers are a way to obtain invariant polynomials on $\mathfrak{gl}(V)=\text{End}(V)$. Instead, use the homogeneous invariant polynomial $p$, in the way you describe. Also, you should be aware that $\varphi_x$ is a sum of terms $\sum q_i\otimes\eta_i$, not necessarily pure. But that is not important. My $\varphi\mapsto\text{tr}(\wedge^d\varphi)$ is your $q$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I see that I can map $\sum_iq_i\otimes\eta_i$ to $\sum_ip(q_i)\otimes\eta_i$ (extending $p:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}$ to $p:\text{ad}P\to\text{ad}P$ (a fibre-preserving map)), but then how can I get an element in $H^0(M, K^d)$?

Comment: Ah, that is a good point that I forgot to mention. This boils down to the transformation rule that the section $\sum p(q_i)\otimes\eta_i$ obeys, because you have applied $p$ to the first factor. It will now transform as a section of the $d$-th symmetric product of $K$, but that is the same as the $d$-th tensor power because $K$ is a line bundle. This follows from the fact that $q$ is homogeneous of degree $d$, and again I would leave the details as an exercise (recall that a polynomial on $\mathfrak{g}$ of homogeneous degree $d$ is the same as an element of $\text{Sym}^d(\mathfrak{g}^*)$.

Comment: Thank you again. I feel out of my depth when it comes to how symmetric products and tensor powers interplay in the case of a line bundle, or how $\sum_ip(q_i)\otimes\eta_i$ "transforms" as an element of a symmetric product of $K$. Can you give me a reference for these constructions (or elaborate)?

Comment: There's a book called "Integrable Systems: Twistors, Loop Groups, Riemann Surfaces" by Hitchin and others. Chapter 2 is written by Hitchin and probably contains the relevant information that you need. What I mean when I say that the section transforms as something, is that you need to look at the expression for $\sum p(q_i)\otimes \eta_i$ in a different choice of coordinates. Because you're applying $p$ to the $q_i$, you will find that the section must transform as a section of the $d$-th tensor power of $K$. It's a good exercise, the book will give you more background if necessary.